# Неправильно работает выборка. Выбираются ненужные элементы

Tags: c#, mysql

Какая то странная вещь началась, а именно: Пишу например примитивный запрос аля выборки из связанных таблиц. А именно выборки имени из таблицы user и выборки из таблицы comment.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnectionStringBuilder mySqlConnectionStringBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            mySqlConnectionStringBuilder.Server = "localhost";
            mySqlConnectionStringBuilder.UserID = "root";
            mySqlConnectionStringBuilder.Password = "";
            mySqlConnectionStringBuilder.Database = "bookkeeping";
            mySqlConnectionStringBuilder.Port = 3306;
            mySqlConnectionStringBuilder.SslMode = MySqlSslMode.None;
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(mySqlConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
            //SELECT bookkeeping.item_set.idSet,bookkeeping.item_set.idBudg,bookkeeping.item_set.Pict,bookkeeping.item.Data," +"bookkeeping.item_set.cost,bookkeeping.comment.Text FROM item_set,comment,item
            // открываем соединение
            connection.Open();
            // запросы
            string query = "SELECT user.Name,comment.Author FROM user INNER JOIN comment ON comment.Author=(SELECT user.idUser FROM user WHERE Name='"+nameUser+"')";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            // объект для выполнения SQL-запроса
            MySqlDataAdapter command = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);

            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            command.Fill(dataSet);
            datagrid_1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];

            // выполняем запрос
            //command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            // закрываем подключение к БД
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Ошибка запроса", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

И суть в том что с join'ом или через простое указание Where user,comment выбирается значения и начинают повторятся по много раз даже те условия которые не подходят под выборку. Вот выкладываю результат запроса:
[image: Результат запроса]

Также выкладываю данные из двух таблиц, и там ясно видно что каждому person'у соответствует уникальный идентификатор.
[image: Таблица comment со значениями]

[image: таблица user со значениями]

И вот прикол в том что с этого запроса должна выводиться только! одна строка, но выводится пять. А если я выбираю данные из всех 5 таблиц которые у меня то у меня повторяются я не считал сколько но примерно раз 50.

Comment: Какой-то странный запрос вы пишете. Почитайте побольше по джойны

Comment: читал а толку то? Я пробовал разные варианты суть в том что оно должно выдать только 1 строку т.к. в бд всего по 5 строк и каждые завязаны на разных Person. А выдает столбик имен Person1 5 штук а 2 столбик idComm идет как 1-5 то есть правильно

Comment: Ваш запрос фактически выглядит так: `SELECT user.Name,comment.Author FROM user INNER JOIN comment ON comment.Author=1`, то есть строки из таблицы `comment`, которые удовлетворяют условию `comment.Author=1` объединяются со всеми строками из таблицы `user`, так как условие таблицу `user` не затрагивает.

Comment: Подзапрос здесь не нужен. Сейчас получается, что: 1) вы никак не ограничиваете user во внешнем запросе, 2) comment никак не связан с user во внешнем запросе. Получается вы выбираете один comment и соединяете его со всеми user

Comment: Посмотрите хотя бы примеры здесь: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL) подзапросы там вообще не используются и не нужны в вашем случае